# How to use prettier with the @hapi/eslint-plugin

Tags: eslint, hapi.js, prettier

I am using hapi.js which comes with it's own style guide and eslint plugin (@hapi/eslint-plugin). I also want to use prettier. The two don't seem to be compatible as the hapi style guide is quite opinionated (which I like).

The main problem I have seen is hapi wants the 1st line of the function to be blank and prettier doesn't.

I have seen lots of posts on this, but was wondering if anyone has actually solved the problem?

Thanks in advance!